# Javascript why is object property ok in header script but undefined in html?

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

The first alert displays correctly "hello" at load time, but when I click on the button, the alert displays "undefined" for exactly the same property.

Tested on firefox quantum, from uwamp and directly from file, tried on IE and edge.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>TestObjectProperty</title>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 

                lang = {
                    greeting: "Hello",
                    bye: "good bye!"
                };

                alert(lang.greeting); 
                //works fine, alert shows Hello

            </script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <button  onclick="alert(lang.greeting);">test lang</button>
        <!-- alert shows UNDEFINED -->
    </body>
</html>
```

I guess I should have "Hello" showing up when the button is clicked.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that lang is an attribute on the current element:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang

If you do `onclick="console.log(lang)"`, you'll see it to be an empty string. Either explicitly define lang in the window scope, or use another variable name such as `_lang`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>TestObjectProperty</title>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 

                window.lang = {
                    greeting: "Hello",
                    bye: "good bye!"
                };

                alert(window.lang.greeting); 
                //works fine, alert shows Hello

            </script>
    </head>
    <body >
        <button  onclick="alert(window.lang.greeting);">test lang</button>
        <!-- alert should show "Hello" -->
    </body>
</html>
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqb5hx6k/2/) for a demonstration.

Comment: Thanks a lot @FrankerZ , indeed, lang is a reserved word! Great answer and nice jsfiddle.